# Deploying updates to a Windows Service application

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I've created a windows service application using Visual Studio .NET 2010 and C#. I've also added an installer application which works great. The application runs great but I have no clue how I am to deploy updates for this application. On a few of the desktop apps that I've created, I can specify that the application check for updates after the program launches. It would be great if I could do the same thing with a window service application. Is this possible? If not, what's the preferred way of deploying updates out to all of my clients?

Comment: possible duplicate of [I want my C# Windows Service to automatically update itself.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106765/i-want-my-c-windows-service-to-automatically-update-itself)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're seeing is a result of the same problem encountered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460118/clickonce-deploy-a-windows-service). This question isn't necessarily a duplicate of that one, but the end-result is the same (See Marc Gravell's answer to that question).