# Using an NT service to auto-update a WPF PRISM application

Tags: c#, wpf, auto-update

I have an msi file that I use to install my application. The application consists of an NT service and a WPF PRISM application. I need an option to auto-update the application with as little user interaction as possible. I want to upgrade both the NT service files and the WPF files.
I thought about using an additional NT service to handle the auto-update process. this new NT service will poll the server and when it detects a newer version of the application on the server it will download it and install it on the client.
what i wanted to ask is this: is this a good option or is there something more suitable that i can use?

Comment: Have you looked into ClickOnce?

Comment: possible duplicate of [I want my C# Windows Service to automatically update itself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106765/i-want-my-c-sharp-windows-service-to-automatically-update-itself)

Comment: One of the easier thing to do is just have the service shut itself off when it detects an update and have a secondary process get fired off that updates the service & then restarts it. Often this can be as simple as process.start() another exe that just copys the files over and restarts the service

Comment: can't use click once since i also need to install a windows service. i' ll look into what @PeterM suggested. it looks promising.